# PHP replace associative array ID values with Name values from another array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I merge PHP arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147/how-can-i-merge-php-arrays)

I have two arrays, both results of db queries. I have a simple example below (no the real data- just for demo purposes. The real data is significantly more complex).

```
$results:

Array 
( [0] => 
  Array ( [id] => 20 [age] => 29 )
  [1] =>
  Array ( [id] => 593 [age] => 38 )
)


$persons:

Array 
( [0] => 
  Array ( [id] => 593 [name] => Jack Jones )
  [1] =>
  Array ( [id] => 20 [name] => John Smith )
)
```

My question is: how can I match the $persons[name] to replace $results[id] so that I end up with:

```
$results:

    Array 
    ( [0] => 
      Array ( [id] => John Smith [age] => 29 )
      [1] =>
      Array ( [id] => Jack Jones [age] => 38 )
    )
```

the arrays are unorderd - I need to replace values if the keys match (and yes, each key in $results definitely has a corresponding entry in $persons). Any help much appreciated!

Comment: See the answer to the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147/how-can-i-merge-php-arrays

Comment: I Tried the final answer in that post but doesn't seem to work. I think it is a little more tricky with a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: @user791335 -- that example is basically the same as the dupes..

Comment: I have to admit I am still struggling. I have tried variations on the answers provided, but not getting the results I want, I think principally because of them being multi-dimensional arrays. I would really appreciated any further pointers.

Comment: @user that example is the **exact same thing** as your question, except it is merged by `id` and yours is by `name` (which you should probably switch)

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array(
array('id'=>58,'name'=>'name1'),
array('id'=>63,'name'=>'name2'),
);
$b = array(
array('id'=>63,'value'=>'value2'),
array('id'=>58,'value'=>'value1'),
);
//making key-value
foreach(array_values($a) as $tmp)
{
      $aProcessed[$tmp['id']]=$tmp['name'];
}
foreach(array_values($b) as $tmp)
{
      $bProcessed[$tmp['id']]=$tmp['value'];
}
//uncomment to see key-value arrays
//var_dump($aProcessed,$bProcessed);
//combining
foreach($aProcessed as $key=>$value)
{
      $result[]=array('name'=>$aProcessed[$key],'value'=>$bProcessed[$key]);   
}
var_dump($result);
```